# Android overflow scrolling bug? Events are not following elements as they scroll

Tags: android, css, mobile, overflow

I'm working on an Android site and can't seem to get overflow scrolling to work correctly on my tablet.

On my device, the items scroll visually as you would expect. But when you press on a scrolled item, it returns the item that would have been in that position if no scrolling had occurred. In the example below, if you scroll to the very bottom and press on `Link 8`, it will return `Link 4`.

I'm running Android 4.0.4 on a Samsung Galaxy Tab (10.1") using the stock browser ("Internet" version 4.0.4-UELPL).

Here my test case: http://jsfiddle.net/davishmcclurg/EhJrS/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
    <li>Link 3</li>
    <li>Link 4</li>
    <li>Link 5</li>
    <li>Link 6</li>
    <li>Link 7</li>
    <li>Link 8</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
}

ul li {
    height: 25%;
}
```

JS:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i += 1) {
    els[i].onclick = function () { alert(this.innerHTML); };
}
```